# Use local file path with jQuery Slider

Tags: 7

I'm trying to set the fotorama jQuery slider to use a local image file path rather than an external web link as I'd like to put a .htaccess on these to prevent hotlinking to them, however, when I do this (put .htaccess on them), it prevents my image sliders from working and I can't seem to find a way to get a local file path to work. I was wondering how I can use a local file path with fotorama? I am using Drupal 7. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide the link for that jquery module, I did find on drupal.org but there is no fotorama jquery slider module. Thanks

Comment: @CodeNext It isn't a module, it is just a standalone jQuery slider. The link to it is: http://fotorama.io/